# cannot ignore .gitignore file in gitbox (.gitignore not ignoring itself)

Tags: git

seems to be a paradox, and it wasn't doing this till about a month ago.  I have a mac with gitbox installed on it, great program and I'm still getting used to the concepts.

However on committingg my changes to a repo, I see the file .gitignore as having been modified.  Well, when I right-click and say Ignore, the .gitignore file itself has .gitignore in it!

Any idea of why this might happened and what I must do about it.  Thanks!

Comment: Note that the `.gitignore` file is *meant to be tracked*. If you have local ignores that you don't want to include with the repository, put them in `.git/info/exclude`. (This is not an answer; a good one is already below. It's just a tip about how these files are usually used.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Git` won't ignore files already committed, even if you list them on `.gitignore`

Use:

```
git rm --cached .gitignore
```

Comment: this appears to have deleted the .gitignore file, but still in the staging area I saw .gitignore showing -but with a "deleted" to the right.  So on a hunch, I went ahead and checked the "deleted" box, did a commit, and .gitignore disappeared from the list THEN.

The magical part is when I created a sample file ignoreme.php and it showed in the staging area, and I right-clicked and selected "Ignore File" - turns out that the gitignore lines for files were still there.  Hey if it works I'm not complaining!

Comment: @SamuelFullman git sometimes is tricky... I'm glad you solved your problem!